# How can I use a react application (e.g. like a Facebook Messenger) in another project?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I want to use my application made in react in another project that is not in react.

How can I create a new instance of my application inside my other project? Something like this:

```
let ReactApp = new ReactApp()
```

Any tips? Do I have to build it in a certain way?

Answer (score 0):

In your React app, when you do:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

What it does is:

1. Compute the react app (Hello, world!)
2. Put the result into the DOM Element with the id: '#root'

You can call ReactDOM.render() on any webpage, any time you want, on multiple DOM Element. And every time, it will create a new version of your React App in your DOM.

---

If you want to export React app to be able to use it somewhere else, I suggest you export your main React component. Then you import it from your other project, and call ReactDOM.render on it:

**MyApp.jsx:**

```
const App = () => <h1>Hello, World!</h1>

export default App
```

**MyOtherApp.jsx:**

```
import MyApp from 'my-app'

ReactDOM.render(MyApp, document.getElementBy('sub-part-of-my-other-app'))
```

Comment: Thank you! I want to actually generate a build to run my react application in other project, because I don't want to have native react language on my other project. Do you have any idea if that is possible?

Comment: You only need "ReactDOM" on your other project. Your other project can be any framework or even none.

`ReactDOM.render(...)` is just a single JS line. Not really "native react language".

Comment: The only other way I see is to use [iframes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe)